# Error code AADSTS70000121 when using One Drive through Microsoft Graph in Java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a Java application that integrates with One Drive through Microsoft Graph. I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java) and I am able to pass the authorisation step but when interrogating the API I get this error:

"*AADSTS70000121: The passed grant is from a personal Microsoft account and is required to be sent to the /consumers or /common endpoint.*"

What am I missing?

This is the code I am using:

1. Get an authorisation token using the URL bellow

```
private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE = "code";
private static final String SCOPE = "openid%20Files.Read%20Files.ReadWrite%20Contacts.Read%20offline_access";

String authorizeUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID
                + "&scope=" + SCOPE + "&response_type=" + RESPONSE_TYPE + "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URL;
```

2. Exchange the received authorization token

```
List<String> scopes = new LinkedList<String>();
scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

AuthorizationCodeCredential authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                    .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .authorizationCode(authorizationCode)
                    .redirectUrl(REDIRECT_URL)
                    .build();

TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, authCodeCredential);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(tokenCredAuthProvider).buildClient();
            
User me = graphClient.me()
                    .buildRequest()
                    .get();
```

Comment: Hi @Tiberiu , have you got resolution , or do still need assistance on this ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @vickykumar! No, I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: Okay , there are couple of question ,my 1st question is why you are adding the scopes in linkedList?  and which article you followed which show you to add scope in this way scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

Comment: could you please try to get the JWT token and check the scopes , please follow the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#step-2-redeem-the-code-for-access-tokens

Comment: Next thing is please provide us the request id and timestamp of your failed call

Comment: The API for TokenCredentialAuthProvider receives a List for scopes parameter. Regarding .default scope please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token

Comment: @vickykumar The step 1. for obtaining the authorization token works just fine. At step 2. I use the autorization token to obtain a GraphServiceClient. Then when I call graphClient.me().buildRequest().get(); it hits that error. Here are the requested details: Trace ID: 2f3441b0-7851-4ce4-b6c9-7c99f3ec1400
Correlation ID: 2f7ff898-4f69-4ef6-a8a2-4bcb8e99aafe
Timestamp: 2022-08-09 08:12:07Z

Comment: what account are you using? is this AAD or Microsoft? and another thing we would like check if the app is disabled in azure portal ?

Comment: It is a personal account for onedrive.live.com that I am trying to connect to the application. The application is active and has Application (client) ID: fab012e5-da76-4dda-8c8d-00893936a6ad

Comment: Thanks for the update , please check the answer in answer box

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the personal account then please change the endpoint to consumers instead of common,
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?

[image]

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: My application is set at Endpoints as OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint (v2) https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize because we target both Microsoft accounts and work or school accounts. Hence we do not want to restrict it to just consumers.

Comment: Thanks for your patience , there are couple of things which we need to figure out , First how is the APP registered, single tenant or multi tenant and secondly check if this is enabled

Enable multi-tenant using the below option in azure.

portal.azure.com -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Select Your App -> Authentication -> Supported account types -> Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)

Comment: It is registered as multi tenant. More exactly I quote from the application settings: "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)
All users with a work or school, or personal Microsoft account can use your application or API. This includes Office 365 subscribers."